# Passing POSIXct to xlim

Tags: r

Would some kind soul please explain why xlim does not acknowledge a POSIXct object as such in the following snippet:

```
y <- rnorm(3)
x <- c("2012-01-01", "2013-01-01", "2014-01-01")
x <- as.POSIXct(x) 
plot(y, xlim=range(x))
```

This results in an empty plot whose xlims are not dates but numeric equivalents and the following error:

```
Error in plot.window(...) : invalid 'xlim' value
```

I scoured old posts and some version of the following allegedly works

```
plot(y, xlim=seq(as.POSIXct("2012-01-01"), as.POSIXct("2014-01-01"), by="month")
```

But I received the same error when I tried. I'd settle for any way to denominate my xtick labels in dates, preferably months.

The snippet above is obviously trivialized to demonstrate my problem but I have verified that my actual x variable is a POSIXct object with dates of the form YYYY-MM-DD and my y is a vector of equal length to x.

Comment: Many thanks; that works. So I'm clear, is it in fact not possible to pass a POSIXct object to xlim?

Comment: @laluajay It seems to be not working.

Comment: @laluajay It works with `xts` object. Posted that as a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try

```
 plot(x,y, xaxt='n')
 axis.POSIXct(side=1, x, format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

Other option is

```
 library(xts)
 x1 <- xts(y, order.by=x)
 plot(x1, xlim=range(index(x1)), type='p')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here in 2024 passing POSIXct values to xlim seems to work.

Here is the original example expanded suggest some helpful practices:

```
par(xpd=F)         # one might have set xpd=T in a previous plot in order to annotate, so keep an eye on this param
y <- c(-1, .5, -.2, .7, 1)
x <- c("2012-01-01", "2013-01-01", "2014-01-01", "2015-01-01", "2016-01-01")
x <- as.POSIXct(x) 
xlimvec = c(x[2], x[4])          # plot only the middle 3 points
# xaxs="i" with axes=F seems like a paradox but it seems to help
plot(x,y,  xlim=xlimvec, xaxs="i",  yaxs = "i", axes=F, col="blue", type="l") 
axis.POSIXct(1, pos = yminaxis, format = "%y-%m-%d")
ytickvec = seq(-1, 1, by= .5)
axis(2, pos = x[2], at = ytickvec)
```